# Write a test cases for custom view

Tags: android, kotlin, junit4, robolectric

A custom view contains several attributes as property, to make this code testable than added unit test (RobolectricTestRunner).

```
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        inflateView()
        bindView()
        initialize()
        setContentHeight()
    }
}
private fun inflateView() {
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.view_custom, this)
}
private fun bindView() {
    panelView = findViewById(R.id.panel_view)
}
private fun setContentHeight(height: Int) {
    layoutParams.height = height <-- test case fail due to layoutParams null.
    requestLayout()
}
```

TestCase

```
    @Test
    fun init() {
        val activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(Activity::class.java).create().get()
        var context = mock(Context::class.java)
        var typedArray = mock(TypedArray::class.java)
        var dropDownView = DropdownTextView(activity, mock(AttributeSet::class.java))

    }
```

> layoutParams having a null object and mock not work here.

Comment: You don't show the usage of `setContentHeight(Int)`. Regardless of this you should not manipulate the layout params like this. Consider overriding `onMessure()` or setting minimal or maximal sizes.

Comment: yes, but the height of view has changing bases on perform click. similar like expandable view. @tynn

Comment: the content of the dropdown height set by `View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec`